# Javascript to change a drop down menu

Tags: javascript

Trying to select a value in a text box after page has loaded but cant seem to get it to work

```
<select class="selectbox required" id="dwfrm_adyenencrypted_expiryMonth" > 
data-missing-error="Please select an Expiration Month" data-parse-error="Invalid value" 
data-range-error="Value too long or too short" data-value->  error="Expiry date is invalid" 
pattern="^(:?0[1-9]|1[0-2])$" required="required" style="display: none;">

<option class="selectoption" label="Month" value="">Month</option>/n
<option class="selectoption" label="01" value="01">01</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="02" value="02">02</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="03" value="03">03</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="04" value="04">04</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="05" value="05">05</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="06" value="06">06</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="07" value="07">07</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="08" value="08">08</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="09" value="09">09</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="10" value="10">10</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="11" value="11">11</option>
<option class="selectoption" label="12" value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

this is the code I am using to try and change the drop down selection:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("dwfrm_adyenencrypted_expiryMonth").options[5].selected = true;void(0);
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678210/select-dropdown-menu-option-with-javascript

Comment: acording to that post I think the code I have entered should work but it doesnt seem to be